# It is possible to add some extra content to the rendable array of a node?

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

I have a hook_node_view_alter implementation in which a recive a node rendable array with its fields, data and stuff

It if possible to add like a fake field to it?

My goal is to print some data but it is nowhere in the node entity, it is not a field or a view or whatver

It is possible?

Edit:

For example i have this array

I have this node rendable array from &$build in my node_view_alter implementation

[image]

Can i like

```
$fake_field = $build['field_hotel'];
$fake_field['#field_name'] = 'field_hotel_2';
$fake_field[0]['#markup'] = 'Some data';
$build['field_hotel_2'] = $fake_field;
```

It still would be rendered?

Comment: Is it just for that one specific node, or for all nodes? Have you tried using templates?

Comment: it is node specific, in the view_alter implementations i do all respective checks. My idea is, like all fields created with field api and trough admin and stuff, in the hook node view alter this fields add its rendable array, can i like copy one of those and change some data and it still would wokr? for example: copy the array of the textfield but change its data and field name or simething like

Comment: Does this mean you dont want to update the field and just pull and change the values..You can use [preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7)

Comment: @GianniDiFalco have you tried adding it with PHP through the node template? if you can give an example of what you are trying to achieve, might be able to offer more specific help.

Comment: Updated question